# How to ship a licensed third party?

Tags: licensing

A free command line utility X can be download from the web.
I have built a utility Y which relies on X.
The license of X does not allow me to bundle it with Y.

Am I allowed to do any of the following?

1. In my README tell the user "go to X site and download it".
2. In my installation get user approval to automatically download X from the web.
3. same as #2 but without user approval.
4. bundle X - it's free anyway (and so is Y).

I know I will not get a perfect legal advise here but I want to hear your opinions.

Comment: You need to talk to a legal expert, or the makers of library X.

Comment: What's the wording on license X that prevents the bundling? (or which license it is, if it's a standard license)

Comment: I prefer not to paste the license, but it clearly specify that the library cannot be incorporated into other software. I do hope that #3 is legal since I do it on the end user behalf (sort of). I write a free software and do not want to involve a lawyer.

Comment: How is a library that can't be incorporated into other software supposed to be used?

Comment: It is a command line utility, not a library.

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that it's an standalone utility, not a library, the cases are very different (since libraries are supposed to be used by other programs in one or another way, but that's not true for applications).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you commented that is not a library but an standalone application, I would read the license carefully because is possible that even **use** the tool from your application is not allowed, maybe it's only free for standalone use.

As other people have commented, you should get legal advice since the legal jargon usually is quite difficult to grasp for non-lawyers...

Comment: let's assume it is legal to use X only as a standalone - this is an end-user agreement which my user needs to follow, not me. So if I let my user decide if he want to install X or not I do not see a problem. The only issue will be that I had to develop against X, but in theory since it is a command line I can develop without it.

Comment: What I tried to say is that you should check that calling the utility from another application is allowed. I know that this makes little sense at first sight, but license agreements can be very restrictive (and sometimes makes little sense for a non-lawyer, including me :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the license.

My understanding of that would be that 1 and 2 are OK, 3 is gray area (i.e. I wouldn't do this) and 4 an absolute no-no.

Of course this is without reading the exact license and simply following your description.

However, I would consult a lawyer if this is a concern.